# Как прочесть датасет

Tags: python

Всем доброго времени. В общем такая проблема. Есть задание - отфильтровать датасет, как можно лучше используя фильтры Opus. Нужно удалить строки, где неправильный перевод с английского на русский, где есть ошибки (грамматические, лексические итд). Все плохие строки удалить очень сложно, в крайнем случае отфильтровать сколько получиться.

Вот библиотека для фильтрации - https://github.com/Helsinki-NLP/OpusFilter, но на свой компец я сейчас не могу ее установить, т.к. у меня python 3.5. И беда в том как прочесть файл с таким расширением `file1.en-ru.en` и `file2.en-ru.ru` не используя сторонние либы???

Comment: расширения файлов ни о чем не говорят кроме языка. вопрос-то в чём? пока кроме жалобы на "компец" ничего в вопросе не понятно.

Comment: А в чём проблема поставить себе нужную версию питона? Или зайти в `Google Colab` и экспериментировать там как хотите.

Comment: @strawdog читая файл по-классически я получаю построково не все строки которые там есть, далеко не все
with open(r"C:\dset\file1.en-ru.en", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line, end="")
чтение идет нормально, потом обрывается с этой ошибкой 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 3754: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Наверное, вам стоит в [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) указать аргумент `encoding`